# Can Coded UI Tests Be Used with External Sites?

Tags: single-sign-on, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to figure out a way to automate testing for Single Sign On (SSO).
For us the process is as follows:

1. The user logs onto https://www.identityprovider.com
2. They click a link that takes them to our authentication server (the application that we are testing).
3. They are automatically logged into one of our web application (www.serviceprovider.com).

Writing useful unit tests for this seems to be difficult because of the protocols used for SSO (SAML, OAuth), and so I thought that a good way to do the testing would be via recorded step testing through something like MS Coded UI tests or Selenium.  We would prefer to go with MS Coded UI tests because of the integration with the VS solution.

That said, can anyone tell me if I can start my CodedUI test from an external website (for example: google.com), or am I limited to my local solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to hand code that.

```
BrowserWindow bw = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri("http://google.com""));
```